# Prevent loss of focus on JList refresh

Tags: java, multithreading, swing

Thanks for taking a look at my question. I'll try to make it as clear and concise as possible.

### The Program

---

Okay so I have implemented a chat program. Part of the functionality of that Chat program is a list of users that are online. This list is updated every 10 seconds. This is the part of the program that I am having trouble with. Every 10 seconds, my Server will send out a packet of all the users that are online, in one CSV String, to each Client. The Client successfully parses the packet, and loads every name into a ListView. All of these things work exactly how I want them to.

### The Problem

---

When the list refreshes, all focus is lost. I imagine this is because all items in the list are replaced, but I'm struggling to think of a way around it. The reason why this is important, is because for the user to send a message to another user, they must click the name in the list, then send the message. Obviously, if it keeps refreshing it makes using the chat program very annoying!

The Strings populate this field:

`private DefaultListModel<String> usersList;`

which is bound to the ListView with this code:

`this.list = new JList(this.usersList);`

and is updated by data from the server, using this method:

```
 public void setOnlineUsersList()
 {
    String[] onlineUsers = this.c.getOnlineUsers();
    // Request the client to query the server for online users. Execution waits until a  response is recieved.
    if (this.usersList.size() > 0) {
        // Ensure there are users online.
        this.usersList.clear();
        // Clear the users from the list, if they need to be replaced.
    }

    for (String s : onlineUsers)
    {
        // Add each username to the DefaultListModel, which updates the ListView.
        this.usersList.addElement(s);
    }
}
```

**Before Online Users List Refreshes**
[image: Before refresh]

**After Online Users List Refreshes**
[image: After Refresh]

### The Question

---

Can you guys offer me any methods whereby a client can select another user from the "online list", and when the list refreshes the ListItem remembers it's focus so the Client doesn't have to keep clicking the user? I'm not looking for code here, or a quick fix by any stretch of the imagination. I've simply been thinking about this for a few days, and I'm stuck now, so any help would be very much appreciated.

Thanks in advance, Chris.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could simply not remove all entries, and instead iterate over the entire list for each name and see if it isn't already in there, in which case you add it. This should retain focus on the item that has it.

Alternatively, you might be able to put a listener on the `JList`, and store the item that is selected, then manually set it as selected after the refresh.

Comment: Thankyou for your suggestion. I implemented the latter; really amazed at how simple the solution was. Odd that I couldn't see it. Ah well, we all have off days. :)

Comment: Indeed we do, I probably no less than you! Happy to help you on one of those days :).